# Function get_plugins() cannot be execute

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to code simple php script which will return all plugins of Wordpress.

My code:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

include('../../../wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');

$all_plugins = get_plugins();

error_log( print_r( $all_plugins, true ) );
```

And my output is:

```
 Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in /home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php:273 Stack trace: #0 /home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/versions.php(6): get_plugins() #1 {main} thrown in /home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 273
```

I used official example from: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins

I did:

- change of PHP version from 7.2 to 5.6
- set right permission of files
- install WordPres once again

So my wordpress is totally fresh and I still have the same error. Somebody knows how to solve it?

Comment: Do you have any other plugin on your site? How yours wp-config.php  like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load all the WordPress functions you need to include the file `wp-load.php`:

`require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");`

and not the plugins one.

Comment: You are my Hero Enrique. I spend so many hours to solve it. I haven't seen anything about wp-load.php. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use at the top of your plugin.

```php
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
```